# onclick in javascript not triggering, while Id is correct

Tags: javascript, html, flask

this is my javascript code the onclick functions do not trigger when i push the button I have tried with an event listener that listen only for the parent of the button aka the form but nothing in that case it fires once and it does not keep listening for further button clicks:

```
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
    const room__message = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#room__message').innerHTML);

     document.querySelector('#send__button').onclick = () =>{
        console.log('hola el boton fue pulsado')
        let message = document.querySelector('#message__input').value
        let user = localStorage.getItem('user')
        let channel = localStorage.getItem('channel')
        console.log(message)
        socket.emit('send message', {'message':message, 'user':user, 'room':channel})
        document.querySelector('#message__input').value = '';
    }

    socket.on('connect', () =>{

        socket.emit('join', { 'channel':localStorage.getItem('channel'), 'user':user })
        load__list();
        load_messages(localStorage.getItem('channel'))
    });

    document.querySelector('#add__room').onclick = () => {
        let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('channel__list'));
        let name_ = prompt("Please enter you'r new Channel's name", "");
         while (name_ in list || name != null){
                name_ = prompt("this name is already in the database", "");
         }
         if (name_ != null){
            list.push(name_)
         }
        socket.emit('new room', {'name':name_})
    };

    socket.on('broadcast', data =>{
        let message = data.message;
        let user = data.user;
        let timestamp = data.timestamp;
        const msj = room__message({'message':message, 'user':user, 'timestamp':timestamp})
            document.querySelector('.message__cont').innerHTML += msj;
    });
});
```

the html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <ul id="channel__list">
        <li>
            <button id="add__room">+</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="chanel__container">
        <form id="channel__form" action="" >
            <input type="text" id="message__input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="message">
            <input type="submit" id="send__button" value="send">        
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

it does run in a flask server I dont know if that may be an issue

Comment: Console errors? Can you provide SO snippet?

Comment: You have bunch of syntax errors here, and you dont have room__message id in HTML. Provide a working snippet with html and js.

Comment: there is no console errors, sorry I try to trim the code as much as i could and maybe cut some necessary stuf let me edit with full js... the room__message is a template outside the body of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are quite a few syntax errors in your code.

## Inside your HTML code

`<from>` tag is to be changed to `<form>`

## Inside your JS code

1. ID **room__message** is not declared hence this will never return anything.
2. You have opened a function socket.io('connect') function but never closed.

   - Coming back to why the on click buttons are not getting triggered *

***The possible reason this could be happening is that by the time your document readyState is already completed in this case the event DOMContentLoaded will not be fired at any point in time. This can be avoided by providing/checking document ready state.***

Below are two sample codes (I am still not sure why you are using on click function inside a listener while you can use JS shorthand and directly use it)

**Proper HTML code**

```
<body>
 <ul id="channel__list">
   <li>
     <button id="add__room">+</button>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="chanel__container">
  <form id="channel__form">
    <input
      type="text"
      id="message__input"
      autocomplete="off"
      placeholder="message"
    />
    <input type="submit" id="send__button" value="send" />
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

**Your actual JS code (a bit modification)**

```
if (document.readyState === "loading") {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadDomContent());
} else {
  console.log("Current document load state: ", document.readyState);
  loadDomContent();
}

function loadDomContent() {
  const room__message = Handlebars.compile(
     document.querySelector("#room__message").innerHTML
  );

 document.querySelector("#send__button").onclick = () => {
    /*         do something */
 };

 socket.on("connect", () => {
    socket.emit("join", {
     /*             do other stuff }); */
    });
 });

document.querySelector("#add__room").click = () => {
  console.log("I am working");
  /*          do something else */
};

socket.on("broadcast", data => {
  /*         send some stuff over */
});
}
```

Also, you can write something like this

```
<button onclick="addNewRoom()" id="add__room">+</button>
```

An declaring that as:

```
function addNewRoom(){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: sorry let me clearfy a little bit more, I tried your suggestion but still have the same problem. the dom contentloaded it fires because by this I am loading the page and so aditional messages, and they load perfectly never the less I tried both of your methods with the same outcome, the buttons are not calling the functions. I even copy pasted your answer fill in my code where it goes with no luck, I have a fresh edit with a little bit more of the code, thanks anyway I know this information will help many others

Comment: Hey can you provide a codesandbox link of your code so that I can have a look

Comment: Honestly i dont know how to

Comment: So there are multiple platforms where you can write your code can generate a shareable link. You can check jsfiddle, codepen. Once you open it you will get to know how you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

### My Solution

the issue was in deed in the html, because it was changing the position of th ebutton by adding more elements to its container im guessing it changed the address to which the event was pointing at, thanks everybody for their input.